# Why isn't a new line being created?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to break the UILabel into 3 parts, the top line will be the Title, second line will be the artist, and the third line will be the album. Why is the UILabel not displaying it in three lines?

```
 var ID3 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,200))
    ID3.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    ID3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    ID3.text = (Title + "\n" + Artist + "\n" + Album)
    self.view.addSubview(ID3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID3.numberOfLines = 3
```

Hope that helps ;) The default value for this property is 1 and if you set it to 0 then you will have a multiline label :)

Edit:
Sample playground code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let Title = "Lorem ipsum title"
let Artist = "lorem ipsum artist"
let Album = "lorem ipsum album"

var ID3 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,200))
ID3.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
ID3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
ID3.text = (Title + "\n" + Artist + "\n" + Album)
ID3.numberOfLines = 3
ID3.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

view.addSubview(ID3)
```

[image]

Comment: I got the uilabel to extend over 3 lines, but how can I assign the first line to the song title, second line to artist, and third line to album because after applying this line of code, The title flows into the second line and the album title starts on the second line and ends on the third line.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I'm not getting what you are saying :)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjdj4uquecrjzif/Screenshot%202015-08-10%2002.05.00.png?dl=0

Comment: If the text of the line can't be fitted then it will flow down :) It's hard to say because you have a white bg on label on on the view is that the case.  Did you try AutoLayout? It will calculate the frame based on the text :)